# How to create a child entity in to-many relationship with JSONAPI

Tags: json-api

I've been reading through jsonapi's docs and I can't wrap my head around how this is practical. According to the docs to add a **comment** to an **article** the comment must already exist.

```
POST /articles/1/relationships/comments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": [
    { "type": "comments", "id": "123" }
  ]
}
```

Is this just a poor example or does the spec really want you to issue a request to create a **comment** that isn't related to an entity before issuing the above request to relate it for a total of 2 requests?

It would seem that you would more likely want to issue a request like this:

```
POST /comments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "comments",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "blah blah blah"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "article": {
        "data": { "type": "articles", "id": "45" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or better yet:

```
POST /articles/45/relationships/comments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": [
    { 
      "type": "comments", 
      "attributes": {
        "body": "blah blah blah"
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've asked a very similar question on discuss.jsonapi.org: http://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/how-should-i-create-a-resource-as-a-relationship/299/2

Answer (score 2):

According to [JSONAPI's guide on creating resources](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating), the following resource creation request, which looks very similar to OP's first suggestion, is a valid request.

```
POST /photos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "photos",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Ember Hamster",
      "src": "http://example.com/images/productivity.png"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "photographer": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a poor example - it is listed under the "Updating To-Many Relationships" section and assumes the comment already exists.  In real life your second example would be fine.

There is a notion of a [client generated](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating-client-ids) id that is passed alongside data, but that assumes the client is capable of producing a globally unique id, which in the case of comments, a client is certainly not.

> A server MAY accept a client-generated ID along with a request to
>   create a resource. An ID MUST be specified with an id key, the value
>   of which MUST be a universally unique identifier. The client SHOULD
>   use a properly generated and formatted UUID as described in RFC 4122
>   [RFC4122].

Comment: A client can't produce a GUID for comments?

Comment: I'm speaking generally to comments being a poor example.  Without central coordination or exchanging additional messages amongst each other, distributed clients cannot make any guarantees about global uniqueness.